# How to "NOT" a register in mips assembly

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, mips, bitwise-operators, boolean-logic

Since there isn't a NOT logical operator in mips assembly, how can one "not" the contents of a register?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `nor` and the `zero`-register to fit everything into one instruction.

```
nor $<dest_reg>, $<in_reg>, $zero

nor $t1, $a0, $zero                # for example
```

The equivalent logical expressions would be:

```
a nor 0 = not (a or 0) = not a
```

Many assemblers, such as MARS and clang, even support `not $dst, $src` as a pseudo-instruction for `nor` with `$zero`.

It's also equivalent to OR with itself instead of zero, such as `nor $t2, $t1, $t1`

---

Another slower approach would be using `xor` and `-1` as this is encoded as `1111...1111` in 2s-component.  But MIPS bitwise-boolean instructions like `xori` zero-extend their immediate operand, not sign-extend, so you need a separate instruction to create a full 32-bit `0xffffffff` in another register (e.g. `addi $at, $zero, -1`).

```
li $<help_reg>, -1                        # load -1 into help-register
xor $<dest_reg>, $<in_reg>, $<help_reg>   # actual not-operation
```

XOR with 0 is a no-op; XOR with 1 produces the inverse of the other input bit.  The equivalent logical expressions (for each bit separately) would be:

```
a xor 1 = not a
```

If you wanted to flip some bits in the low 16 of a register but leave others unmodified, `xori` can do that in a single instruction.  For example to just flip a boolean 0 / 1, such as

```
slt $t0, $t1, $t2          # produce a boolean 0 / 1
xori $t0, $t0, 1           # *logical* NOT the boolean, producing 1 / 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Load -1 into another register, then XOR the registers.

[https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/bitwise.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20051203194104/www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/bitwise.html)
(Archived version of the web-page as the original link was broken)

Comment: link is broken...